Can I use dual HDMI output on macbook air m3 with only 1 usb-c cable?
It's well known that the macbook air m3 supports double monitor output. I bought a ugreen usb-c hub with dual monitor HDMI output, and was able to use in my dell XPS 13 without any problems, with only 1 usb-c port. But on the macbook it basically outputs the same screen to both outputs, recognizing as a single monitor.
I have to use 2 usb-c HDMI adaptors: one being the hub, and the other being another usb-c HDMI dongle.
Is it possible to have everything into just one usb-c port?
I even tried connecting the dongle on the usb-c hubś 5gbps usb-c output, but it didn't get recognized.

Which ugreen usb-c hub? Which other usb-c HDMI adaptor?

Most likely the hub has Multi-Stream Transport capability which is offered by Windows but not by macOS.

@DavidAnderson I forgot to mention it's not windows but ubuntu.

@DavidAnderson this hub https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32821301992.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2bra. Do you know one that works?

Which version of Ubuntu?

Did you realize the link you gave shows an image where macOS will not do what you asked about in your question?

@DavidAnderson ubuntu 24.04. Indeed, now that I saw the description, it explains exactly that. So it looks like MST is needed and macOS does not support, so I think no dual HDMI hubs exist for macOS right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
